# Plotar o resultado da PCA em três dimensões

Tags: r, ggplot2

Fiz uma PCA utilizando `stats::prcomp` e gostaria de plotar o resultado em três dimensões. É possível?

Answer (score 2):

Use a função `pca3d` do pacote de mesmo nome:

```
library(pca3d)

irisPCA <- prcomp(iris[, -5], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)

pca3d(irisPCA, group = iris$Species)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]